# Using HttpClient in destructor

Tags: c#, destructor, dotnet-httpclient

I want to post some exception data (if present) to a server when my program ends.

I have a destructor that is triggered on the main window view model destructor..

I run this:

```
 ~ProgramWizardViewModel()
 {
    if ((Program.Errors.Count > 0)
                     && (WizardData?.User != null))
    {
        string errorsText = string.Format(string.Join("\n", Program.Errors));
        WizardData.client.UploadExceptionReport(errorsText);
    }
}
```

WizardData.client has a method UploadExceptionReport (that i copied from SO)

```
public void UploadExceptionReport(String s)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var uri = new Uri(Program.ServerUri + "api/exception_report");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("exception_string", s)
        });
        var result = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
        string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
    }
}
```

But at the client.PostAsync, debugging stops entirely, with no exceptions, and returns:

> The program '[3364] Program.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I am guessing this is because of the way the async. POST makes a thread to send off its request, but the destructor finalises and the object is lost before it can execute.

So: what would be a good way to POST this data on program close?
What could be the reason this code fails?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `AppDomain.UnhandledException`? Or some other event on form closing.

Comment: Try taking out the Async send and use a blocking one.  The Async is allowing the calling thread to process causing your main app to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this in the wrong place.

You should override the OnFormClosing method  or set up a handler for the OnClosing event.

The reason for this is that you don't need any random weirdness in the user interface -- the logging you're trying to do should happen *between* the time the program (or the user) invokes the "close", but before the form disappears from view.  You could even change the mouse-pointer to the "Timer".  If you do the logging async, consider whether or not to call DoEvents repeatedly while it's occurring, to keep the UI from appearing that it has locked up if the HTTP request takes a while.

OnFormClosing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

OnClosing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx

DoEvents: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Putting the code there makes good design sense to me.  I found incorporating a form closing event handler  into the  MVVM pattern to be not as easy as it should be....

Answer (score 0):

Try making it async.

```
~ProgramWizardViewModel()
{
    if ((Program.Errors.Count > 0)
                     && (WizardData?.User != null))
    {
        string errorsText = string.Format(string.Join("\n", Program.Errors));
        WizardData.client.UploadExceptionReport(errorsText).Wait();
    }
}
```

And

```
public async Task UploadExceptionReport(String s)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var uri = new Uri(Program.ServerUri + "api/exception_report");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("exception_string", s)
        });
        var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
    }
}
```

Maybe now the destructor will wait for the http client async task to finish.